# How to compare columns with equal values?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe which looks as follows:

```
   colA  colB

0    2    1
1    4    2
2    3    7
3    8    5
4    7    2
```

I have two datasets one with customer code and other information and the other with addresses plus related customer code.

I did a merge with the two bases and now I want to return the lines where the values ​​in the columns are the same, but I'm not able to do it.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: this is an inner join `pd.merge(table_a,table_b,left_on=['ColA'],right_on=['ColB'],how='inner')` will return matching rows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try :

```
dfs=df.loc[df['colA']==df['colB']]
```

Comment: I managed to do that! Can you tell me how you could do it with 3 columns?

Comment: you can use `dfs=df.loc[(df['colA']==df['colB']) & (df['colC']==df['colB']) ] `

Comment: `df[df.min(axis=1)==df.max(axis=1)]`?